# How to get rows from table

Tags: sql

I have table `recipes2ingredients`

```
(id, recipe_id, ingredient_id)
```

and 2 ingredients for example 1,2. I need get all recipe_id

```
where  is ingredient_id = 1 and ingredient_id = 2
```

Comment: So, is ingredient_id has multiple values? It's not a good database design, it violates the first normal form (1NF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a having and a count and a where you can find all recipes that have both ingredients.

```
SELECT recipe_ID, count(Distinct ingredient_id)
FROM recipes2ingredients
WHERE ingredient_ID in (1,2)
GROUP BY recipe_id
HAVING count(Distinct ingredient_id) = 2
```

A distinct count is used so if perchance an ingredient is listed more than once, we don't get a false positive.

The where clause limits to just those recipes having one or more of the ingredients and the having clause ensures that we only have 2

This approach has the advantage of allowing both the where clause and the having count to be variables provided at run time without having to change the query structure.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is to be used on DB server; you can use.

```
select distinct r2i1.recipe_id from recipes2ingredients r2i1
join recipes2ingredients r2i2
on r2i1.recipe_id = r2i2.recipe_id
where r2i1.ingredient_id = 1
and r2i2.ingredient_id = 2;
```

Comment: This works so long as the user doesn't need a variable number of ingredients on each query. It doesn't scale well beyond a limit of 2.